# hibernate validation exception handling in spring boot application when my application not having any controllers, not having controlleradvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I build application where I am not using any `@RestConttroller`. Its like pure java application using Spring boot. In this I Used Hibernate-validation.

Below is the DTO.

Now when `@NotBlank` validation is happening, I am not able to catch that exception.

As I know `@ControllerAdvice` will work when we have controllers in the Application.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
@Data
@Validated
public class Config {
    @NotBlank
    private String host;
    @NotBlank
    private String port;
    @NotBlank
    private String username;
}
```

Comment: You are using validation on configuration properties, failing validation will just stop the application from starting with an error explaining what is wrong. This is part of the startup process of the application.

Comment: is there is any way i can catch this error and show a meaningfull error. As developer point of view this error message is clear but think in a way where a person who is going to use this application having ZERO technical understanding .

Comment: Not without reimplementing parts of the error handling in Spring Boot. Also if I recall correctly it tells you which property (with name and all) has a wrong value already, so not sure if that is really an issue?

Comment: As i mentioned there is not issue if developer will see the error, developer can understand the error easily but non technical guy will face some problem. Can you give me some idea, if i want to reimplement the error handling part.

Comment: That means rewriting part of Spring Boot. imho this is something you need to fix with documentation (installation guide, faq etc).